# No route registered for '/api/functions/admin/token'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I have 2 functions and have written a powershell script to get the JWT for the Azure Function app. In one of the functions, it's working and in the other, it's not. Below is a part of my script which I am using for generating the JWT:

```
$ResourceGroupName = <resource_group_name>
$functionAppName = <function_app_name>

$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
$resourceName = "$functionAppName/publishingcredentials"
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword)))

$jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$functionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions/admin/token" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) } -Method GET
```

The only difference that I could see between the 2 function apps is: the script works for a `Java` function of Version `2` and the function where the script doesn't work is a `Python` function of Version `3`.

I also tried to generate a token from [Azure official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getfunctionsadmintoken) and it failed with the same error `No route registered for '/api/functions/admin/token'`. I then created a new function app in Python (Version 3) in a different subscription and tried the same and it worked for the new function app, but not for the previous one.

Here are a few lines before the error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod: /home/vsts/work/1/s/setKeyFunctionCode.ps1:72
Line |
  72 |      $jwt = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$functionAppName.scm.azure …
     |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No route registered for '/api/functions/admin/token'
```

Is there some configuration that I'm missing out?
Please help me figure out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message in detail?

Comment: That's all the error message is stating. I have updated the description now to display a few lines before the error message.

Comment: Could you please tell me which type plan you use with java and python function? Linux or windows?

Comment: The Java function is using `Windows` OS and having the Plan `Y1`.
Both Python functions that I've mentioned are running in `Linux` OS. The app service plan for the Python function for which I'm able to get the token is `Y1` and the plan for the Python function for which I'm not able to get the token is using the Plan `S1`.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you call the API? In normal, we call the API to get jwt then call key management API: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API

Comment: I call the function app using the JWT. Basically, I'm using the JWT as some kind of a signature and let the requests through. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Is that you use jwt to project your function app?

Comment: I have an API Gateway where the JWT will be validated and then the request to the function will be let through. If the JWT is invalid, the API Gateway will ignore the request.

Comment: Since so, I think you need to use different identity providers to generate jwt. then call your  function, such as Facebook Azure AD, etc. The  jwt you generate now is used to call some api to manage function app.

Comment: When I generate JWT for a function app that's deployed in `Y1` subscription, the path `/api/functions/admin/token` is found. If I deploy the exact same function app in another plan that has `S1` subscription, the corresponding path is not present and I'm getting the error. I looked in Azure documentations, but couldn't find anything relating to this.